# ¿Cómo poner un espacio cada vez que encuentre el símbolo "– " en un texto?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una página en HTML para albergar varios cuentos, pero me gustaría que al pasar el texto a la página se pusiera un espacio a la izquierda cada vez que se encuentre con el símbolo **"–"**, que es el símbolo de los diálogos entre los personajes. Esto lo pienso con el objetivo de que la lectura sea más clara.

[image: Me gustaría que al final se vería así, pero solo consigo que se vea todo justificado, solo me falta eso]

Adjunto mi código en HTML:

```css
.cuento p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cuento</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cuento">
    <p>Érase una vez una preciosa niña que siempre llevaba una capa roja con capucha para protegerse del frío. Por eso, todo el mundo la llamaba Caperucita Roja.</p>
    <p>Caperucita vivía en una casita cerca del bosque. Un día, la mamá de Caperucita le dijo:</p>
    <p>– Hija mía, tu abuelita está enferma. He preparado una cestita con tortas y un tarrito de miel para que se la lleves ¡Ya verás qué contenta se pone!</p>
    <p> </p>
    <p>– ¡Estupendo, mamá! Yo también tengo muchas ganas de ir a visitarla – dijo Caperucita saltando de alegría.</p>
    <p>Cuando Caperucita se disponía a salir de casa, su mamá, con gesto un poco serio, le hizo una advertencia:</p>
    <p>– Ten mucho cuidado, cariño. No te entretengas con nada y no hables con extraños. Sabes que en el bosque vive el lobo y es muy peligroso. Si ves que aparece, sigue tu camino sin detenerte.</p>
    <p>– No te preocupes, mamita – dijo la niña- Tendré en cuenta todo lo que me dices.</p>
    <p>– Está bien – contestó la mamá, confiada – Dame un besito y no tardes en regresar.</p>
    <p>– Así lo haré, mamá – afirmó de nuevo Caperucita diciendo adiós con su manita mientras se alejaba.</p>
    <p>Cuando llegó al bosque, la pequeña comenzó a distraerse contemplando los pajaritos y recogiendo flores. No se dio cuenta de que alguien la observaba detrás de un viejo y frondoso árbol. De repente, oyó una voz dulce y zalamera.</p>
    <p>– ¿A dónde vas, Caperucita?</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

He visto problemas similares al mío y he tratado de resolverlo, pero mejor no adjunto nada, puesto que no pude resolverlo. De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo concreto para no modificar el origen añadiendo un tabulador (por ejemplo) y querer modificarlo dinamicamente?
Por ejemplo, en el editor de texto que uses, buscar y reemplazar para insertar los espacios, o la class.

Answer (score 8):

> He probado las soluciones aportadas (además de útiles) y todas funcionan. Sin embargo, voy a aprovechar de poner mi grano de arena sobre este tema.
>
> Por otra parte, se coloca la solución al principio para que pueda evaluarlo. Luego de eso, se explicará más abajo cómo funciona. Le será de mucha ayuda.

### Una solución de muchas otras posibles

Pruébela y evalúe sus resultados:

```js
const parrafos = document.querySelectorAll("p");

const evaluar = (parrafo) => {
  // Expresión para encontrar el primer guión:
  let expresion = /^(\–)/g;

  // Se obtiene el contenido del parrafo y se elimina el guión:
  let texto = parrafo.textContent.trim();
  parrafo.textContent = texto.replace(expresion, "");
  return expresion.test(texto);
}

parrafos.forEach(parrafo => {
  if (evaluar(parrafo)) {
    parrafo.classList.add("padding-left");
  }
});
```

```css
.cuento p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}


/* Código CSS nuevo */

.padding-left {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.padding-left::before {
  content: "–";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuento">
  <p>Érase una vez una preciosa niña que siempre llevaba una capa roja con capucha para protegerse del frío. Por eso, todo el mundo la llamaba Caperucita Roja.</p>
  <p>Caperucita vivía en una casita cerca del bosque. Un día, la mamá de Caperucita le dijo:</p>
  <p>– Hija mía, tu abuelita está enferma. He preparado una cestita con tortas y un tarrito de miel para que se la lleves ¡Ya verás qué contenta se pone!</p>

  <p> </p>
  <p>– ¡Estupendo, mamá! Yo también tengo muchas ganas de ir a visitarla – dijo Caperucita saltando de alegría.</p>
  <p>Cuando Caperucita se disponía a salir de casa, su mamá, con gesto un poco serio, le hizo una advertencia:</p>
  <p>– Ten mucho cuidado, cariño. No te entretengas con nada y no hables con extraños. Sabes que en el bosque vive el lobo y es muy peligroso. Si ves que aparece, sigue tu camino sin detenerte.</p>
  <p>– No te preocupes, mamita – dijo la niña- Tendré en cuenta todo lo que me dices.</p>
  <p>– Está bien – contestó la mamá, confiada – Dame un besito y no tardes en regresar.</p>
  <p>– Así lo haré, mamá – afirmó de nuevo Caperucita diciendo adiós con su manita mientras se alejaba.</p>
  <p>Cuando llegó al bosque, la pequeña comenzó a distraerse contemplando los pajaritos y recogiendo flores. No se dio cuenta de que alguien la observaba detrás de un viejo y frondoso árbol. De repente, oyó una voz dulce y zalamera.</p>
  <p>– ¿A dónde vas, Caperucita?</p>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, necesitamos explicarla.

#### Caso CSS

Se crean dos reglas CSS con un selector de clase `.padding-left {}`.

La primera regla es para posicionar los párrafos (`position: relative`) que tienen los guiones y la segunda para colocarle el guión que se le quitó con JavaScript. Pero, en la primera regla se agrega el espacio a la izquierda mediante relleno (`padding-left: 30px`).

Se posiciona el párrafo para que los guiones que se encuentran en el `pseudo-elemento` `::before` no se escapen de él.

En esta primera regla posicionamos el párrafo y le agregamos un espacio mediante relleno:

```css
.padding-left {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

En esta segunda regla CSS utilizamos un `pseudo-elemento` para colocarle el guión (`–`) que previamente le habíamos quitado con JavaScript:

```css
.padding-left::before {
  content: "–";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;

  /* Se necesita para que el guion (-) 
     no quede muy a la izquierda */
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

#### Caso JavaScript

En JavaScript, lo que haremos es extraer todos los párrafos y averiguar cuáles de ellos empiezan con guión (`–`).

Obtenemos nuestra lista de nodos (en este caso, los párrafos):

```js
const parrafos = document.querySelectorAll("p");
```

Crearemos nuestra función `evaluar( parrafo )` para evaluar, cada párrafo y conocer quién contiene un guión (`–`) al principio.

```js
const evaluar = (parrafo) => {
    ...
}
```

Al párrafo que contenga el guión (`–`) al principio se le eliminará de su contenido y se le asignará en su lugar una clase (`padding-left`).

La clase que se le colocará es la que le incorporará el espacio hacia la izquierda.

#### Funcionamiento interno de la función `evaluar( parrafo )`

Nuestra función consta de cuatro (04) líneas que se explican a continuación:

Una expresión regular que definiremos para encontrar el guión (`–`):

```js
let expresion = /^(\–)/g;
```

Una cadena de texto que extraeremos del párrafo y lo almacenaremos en nuestra variable texto:

```js
let texto = parrafo.textContent.trim();
```

Le quitamos el guión (`–`) al contenido que extraeremos de la variable `texto` antes de enviar nuevamente al párrafo:

```js
parrafo.textContent = texto.replace(expresion, "");
```

Y por último, mediante nuestra expresión regular definida en `expresion` evaluaremos si el texto original del párrafo que se pretendió evaluar poseía un guión al principio de su contenido:

```js
return expresion.test(texto);
```

Devolverá un `true` o `false` en función de lo descrito anteriomente.

#### Expresión regular

En cuanto a la expresión regular, el símbolo *circunflejo* (`^`) significa que debe encontrar el primer elemento. En ese caso, el guión (`–`). Los paréntesis funcionan como signos de agrupación. Esa es su función.

`\–` Es el guión (`–`) que se pretende encontrar.

Si quiere saber más sobre expresiones regulares consulte [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) de la documentación del **Sitio Web Oficial de Mozilla.**

#### Iteración de párrafos

Y para finalizar, iteramos los párrafos:

```js
parrafos.forEach(parrafo => {
  ...
});
```

Para evaluarla con `evaluar( parrafo )`:

```js
if (evaluar(parrafo)) {
  ...
}
```

Y le asignaremos la clase `padding-left` al párrafo que tiene el guión (`–`) al principio de su contenido para asignarle su espacio a la izquierda:

```js
parrafo.classList.add("padding-left");
```

Obviamente, si `evaluar( parrafo )` devuelte `true`.

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder, en verdad todos sirven, ya lo resolví gracias a ustedes, ya me di cuenta que me falta más sobre javascript, siento que me estoy perdiendo muchas formas de resolver problemas.

Comment: De forma personal @Nathan yo creo que esta es sin duda  la mejor respuesta a tu problema

Answer (score 2):

Este problema puede resolverse si se agrupan a los elementos por clases, explico:

- Determinado número de párrafos se saben tendrán el símbolo *-* al inicio de los mismos
- Cuando declares esos párrafos o los generes de forma dinámica (*si es que estos provienen por ejemplo de una bd*) dales una clase por ejemplo `cuento-parrafos__dialogo`
- Por medio de CSS dales a cada uno de esos párrafos un margen a la izquierda respecto de su contenedor padre que en este caso sería el `div` con la clase `cuento`

Ejemplo:

```html
    <style>
      .cuento-parrafos_dialogo {
        margin-left: 25px;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="cuento">
        <p>Érase una vez una preciosa niña que siempre llevaba una capa roja con capucha para protegerse del frío. Por eso, todo el mundo la llamaba Caperucita Roja.</p>
        <p>Caperucita vivía en una casita cerca del bosque. Un día, la mamá de  Caperucita le dijo:</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– Hija mía, tu abuelita está enferma. He preparado una cestita con tortas y un tarrito de miel para que se la lleves ¡Ya verás qué contenta se pone!</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– ¡Estupendo, mamá! Yo también tengo muchas ganas de ir a visitarla – dijo Caperucita saltando de alegría.</p>
        <p>Cuando Caperucita se disponía  a salir de casa, su mamá, con gesto un poco serio, le hizo una advertencia:</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– Ten mucho cuidado, cariño. No te entretengas con nada y no hables con extraños. Sabes que en el bosque vive el lobo y es muy peligroso. Si ves que aparece, sigue tu camino sin detenerte.</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– No te preocupes, mamita – dijo la niña- Tendré en cuenta todo lo que me dices.</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– Está bien – contestó la mamá, confiada – Dame un besito y no tardes en regresar.</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– Así lo haré, mamá – afirmó de nuevo Caperucita diciendo adiós con su manita mientras se alejaba.</p>
        <p>Cuando llegó al bosque, la pequeña comenzó a distraerse contemplando los pajaritos y recogiendo flores. No se dio cuenta de que alguien la observaba detrás de un viejo y frondoso árbol. De repente, oyó una voz dulce y zalamera.</p>
        <p class="cuento-parrafos_dialogo">– ¿A dónde vas, Caperucita?</p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

*Aunque seguro existen mejores opciones de lograrlo ;)*

**Referencia**

- [Margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 2):

Además de añadirle la clase para señalar los párrafos donde quieres que se apliquen esos estilos, haría lo siguiente:

1. Eliminar el guión (-) del html
2. Añadirlo con css y así añadirle espacios

   ```
   .cuento p::before {
       content: '- ';
   }
   ```

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 2):

Ten presente la diferencia entre `-` y `—`, dependiendo de la fuente pueden verse iguales pero son códigos de caracter distintos, el primero es el signo de "menos", el segundo es ligeramente mas largo que el primero; tu texto usa el segundo.

Con javascript/jQuery agregamos una clase a los párrafos que comiencen con `–`.

```js
$( function(){
    Array.from(
      document.getElementsByTagName('p')
    ).forEach(
      function(e){
        if( e.innerText.match(/^[-–]/) )
          e.classList.add("dialogo");
      }
    )
  }
);
```

```css
.cuento p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

.cuento .dialogo{
    margin-left: 12px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cuento</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cuento">
    <p>Érase una vez una preciosa niña que siempre llevaba una capa roja con capucha para protegerse del frío. Por eso, todo el mundo la llamaba Caperucita Roja.</p>
<p>Caperucita vivía en una casita cerca del bosque. Un día, la mamá de  Caperucita le dijo:</p>
<p>– Hija mía, tu abuelita está enferma. He preparado una cestita con tortas y un tarrito de miel para que se la lleves ¡Ya verás qué contenta se pone!</p>
<p> </p>
<p>– ¡Estupendo, mamá! Yo también tengo muchas ganas de ir a visitarla – dijo Caperucita saltando de alegría.</p>
<p>Cuando Caperucita se disponía  a salir de casa, su mamá, con gesto un poco serio, le hizo una advertencia:</p>
<p>– Ten mucho cuidado, cariño. No te entretengas con nada y no hables con extraños. Sabes que en el bosque vive el lobo y es muy peligroso. Si ves que aparece, sigue tu camino sin detenerte.</p>
<p>– No te preocupes, mamita – dijo la niña- Tendré en cuenta todo lo que me dices.</p>
<p>– Está bien –contestó la mamá, confiada – Dame un besito y no tardes en regresar.</p>
<p>– Así lo haré, mamá – afirmó de nuevo Caperucita diciendo adiós con su manita mientras se alejaba.</p>
<p>Cuando llegó al bosque, la pequeña comenzó a distraerse contemplando los pajaritos y recogiendo flores. No se dio cuenta de que alguien la observaba detrás de un viejo y frondoso árbol. De repente, oyó una voz dulce y zalamera.</p>
<p>– ¿A dónde vas, Caperucita?</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder